iframe vidoes not blocked in modal popups as fancybox or lightbox
i am using Complianz for controlling and setting cookies on my website. Manually embedded IFrames are blocked if the user not accept the cookies, its working fine. But i would like to open the video via modal popups as lightbox or fancybox.
<a class="vimeo" class=”cmplz-stats” data-fancybox="video-gallery" data-src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/876283694?autoplay=false">
                    <img alt="" width="200" src="https://www.website.com/myposter.jpg">
                </a>

when the user clicks on the image, a fancy modal comes up and the video is shown. Unfortunately unblocked, even if the user does not accept the cookies. fancy box has some developer options, but i could not find a solution
$("[data-fancybox]").fancybox({
        // Customize Fancybox options as needed

        iframe: {
            css: {
                maxWidth: '50%'
            },
            preload: false,
            smallBtn: false,
        }
    });

are there alternatives as lightbox or fancybox with proper options. or would you suggest to do it without a plugin?

I do not understand what is your issue. Just enable Fancybox after user has accepted the cookies. What is stopping you from doing that?

@Janis this is one way to do it. but i would like to show the player with the message inside, where he can accept the cookies.

Then use API (for example, reveal event) to add your custom message over the content.
